# How to convert from NSMutableArray to NSMutableData?

Tags: iphone

How to convert from NSMutableArray to NSMutableData ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArchiver/archivedDataWithRootObject:)

```
NSData *data = [NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myMutableArray];
NSMutableData* mutableData = [data mutableCopy];
```